# Hadoop2.7.0 NameNode FORMAT java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I downloaded Hadoop source code to localy import Hadoop source code into the Eclipse workspace.

I added `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` into 
`hadoop-2.7.0-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java`
dir content.

In Eclipse I ran `NameNode.java`

```
java NameNode.java -format
```

I get the following error message:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.getStorageDirectory(NNStorage.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.initJournals(FSEditLog.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog.initJournalsForWrite(FSEditLog.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:984)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1428)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1553)
2016-06-17 11:12:54,404 INFO  util.ExitUtil (ExitUtil.java:terminate(124)) - Exiting with status 1
2016-06-17 11:12:54,405 INFO  namenode.NameNode (LogAdapter.java:info(47)) - SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at localhost/127.0.0.1
************************************************************/
```

My `core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:///Users/Joker/tmp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

My `hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file://code/java/hadoop2.7.0/dfs/name</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file://code/java/hadoop2.7.0/dfs/data</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I did not set `HADOOP_HOME`, I just want to run `NameNode` in source code.

Comment: I think you need to drop the file:/ for dfs.namenode.name.dir and dfs.datanode.data.dir.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue...

Answer (score 3):

Actually you have set the path like this given below in core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

```
  <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>
   </property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/Users/Joker/tmp</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

And in hdfs-site.xml like this.

```
   <configuration>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
    </property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/code/java/hadoop2.7.0/dfs/name</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/code/java/hadoop2.7.0/dfs/data</value>
   </property>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue for me, the paths are correct